# Android Firebase ML-Kit real time Barcode Detection through Camera

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I have a situation where i have to detect barcode from camera on fly without taking picture using Firebase ML-Kit Vision API.help appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have started with sample provided. and got my desired result.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes

Comment: So the question can be closed..?

Comment: yes i think so.

Comment: If you need a hand doing that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96283/391940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward as opposed to what i thought. below are the official links both to quick-start sample and also the official documentation.
[Firebase ML-kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes)
[sample guide](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ML Kit Showcase App with Material Design](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/material-showcase). It contains both

- the code calling the new ML Kit Standalone API (you can use it without getting a Firebase Id), and
- the Code for putting together a really nice UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use cameraview library to pass frames in realtime to firebase ml kit

Answer (score -1):

Follow this codelab it have everything you want

[Barcode on fly](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0)

Comment: No dear. Its not about google vision. its is about Firebase ML-kit vision.thanks for your kind reply